# Как RC4 xor`ит простой текст и гамма последовательность

Tags: c++, массивы, шифрование, криптография

1.Сначала у нас идет инициализация блока(наш массив).
2.Затем идет перемешивание, где вместо элементов i массива, равных их порядковому номера ставится значение j.
3.Потом генерируется псевдослучайное слово/последовательность.
4.Последовательность должна наложиться на текст.

Как она накладывается на текст?
У нас есть массив и гаммирующая последовательность.

/

```
* ключевое расписание */
void rc4_init( unsigned const char* key, unsigned int key_length )
{
unsigned char temp;

for( i = 0; i != 256; ++i )
S[ i ] = i;

for( i = j = 0; i != 256; ++i )
{
j = ( j + key[ i % key_length ] + S[ i ] ) % 256;
temp = S[ i ];
S[ i ] = S[ j ];
S[ j ] = temp;
}

i = j = 0;
}

/* Вывод одного псевдослучайного байта */
unsigned char rc4_output()
{
unsigned char temp;

i = ( i + 1 ) % 256;
j = ( j + S[ i ] ) % 256;

temp = S[ j ];
S[ j ] = S[ i ];
S[ i ] = temp;

return S[ ( temp + S[ j ] ) % 256 ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Каждый байт данных XOR'ится с байтом последовательности. Например так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; i++){
    data[i] ^= rc4_output();
}
```

Comment: что есть data[i] в этом тексте? Наш открытый текст?  rc4_output() - что несет эта функция?

Comment: в  char data[n] мы считываем все из файла, так? Затем мы генерируем последовательность битов prga ,  что дальше?
Можно конкретнее ,пожалуйста . Вот этот момент плохо понятен

Comment: В данном случае data[] что открытый текст, что закрытый. Операция шифрования и расшифровки одинаковы. Сколько туда читать из файла - вам решать.

Comment: Текст **посимвольно** соединяется каждый раз со случайно сгенерированным (prga) словом, так?

Comment: И получится ли вашим способом записать массив данных в файл?

Comment: Зачем вы говорите о каких-то символах, если речь идет о байтах? И в моем коде ничего нет о записи в файл. Нужно писать в файл - пишите.

Comment: Здесь ведь идет речь о с++ . Разве byte в нем не заменяется на char?

Comment: Может и заменяется, но речь идет о байтах, как о совокупности 8 бит.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing char обычно в C занимает 8 бит, и конечно от слова "символ", но в наше время символы часто бывают более 8 бит в размере, поэтому все таки стоит называть это байтом. особенно когда разговор про шифрование. А что до работы с файлами, так процессор всегда работает только с оперативной памятью. Читаете блок данных из файла в массив, _побайтно_ шифруете, пишите этот блок в файл (тот же или другой), читаете следующий блок и т,п.

Comment: Точно, char же 1 байт. Вот оно что значит побайтно...Спасибо! Все было под носом...